# Magnetic force from a solenoid on a ferromagnetic plunger

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

I'm having a hard time trying to understand a very basic electromagnetism related question, related to how a solenoid valve works. Consider the image below:

[image]

Why is there a force exerted on a ferromagnetic material (at rest, i.e. zero initial velocity) concentric with a solenoid fed with DC current?

I would say that besides the on/off moments, where there is a variation of the magnetic field, the field will be constant and therefore no force would exist.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the fact that the field of the solenoid (which is relatively uniform inside the coil) will magnetize the core and create magnetic poles in it (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#/media/File:Commercial_Solenoid_Dawes_1920.png)). The interaction of the field of the coil with the field of the core will pull the plunger into the coil.

Comment: It must be pretty obvious, but I don't understand what interaction is that. Essentially, why will two magnets attract if the magnetic field is constant?

Comment: The field outside the coil is not uniform. If you look at the picture, the density of the H-lines outside the coil changes, which means that there is a gradient. If you imagine a very long coil, say 1 meter, and a 10 cm rod, it will move inside until the field becomes relatively constant.
And the reason why two magnets interact is still the Lorentz force. You can roughly understand a magnet as a set of microscopic current loops. The electrons cirling within them will be affected by the external magnetic field via the Lorentz force.

Comment: But my problem understanding this is that Lorentz force describes a system where I know the electrical current (q.v), but I can't relate this with the magnetic strength of a magnet.

Comment: There is a direct relation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_moment.

Comment: For the simpliest case of a charge q circling around an orbit of radius r, the magnetic moment is: (1/2)q[rv], for a magnet you would have a set of such loopls and the total magnetization would be an integration over the volume containing all of them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_magnetization

Comment: I think I understand now. For the sake of completeness, could you include the equations and the explanation from the comments in the answer above?